# How do I use the date filter in angularjs to remove invalid dates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angluarjs date filter as follows to get short date:

seniority date {{e.cntySnrDte | date : short}}

and it works perfectly; however, is there a way to to put a phrase "unavailable" instead of the date whenever I run into date value of 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000

for example right now it say:

```
seniority date Aug 19, 2001
```

but if the date is invalid, like

```
seniority date Dec 31, 1899
```

I want it to say

```
seniority date unavailable
```

thanks
Nick

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own filter that delegates to the built-in one on valid inputs.

```
app.filter('myDate', function($filter) {
  return function(input, format) {
    var isInputValid = ... //do your check here for whatever your version of invalid inputs is
    return isInputValid ? $filter('date')(input, format) : 'unavailable';
  };
});
```